# Does ARC release memory in cascade?

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

Say there is an object A

A has a strong reference to B

B has a strong reference to C

Now, say the last reference to A is removed. Say A is in a stack and the function ends.

So A is gone.

At it's dying breadth, does A notify B that it's gone? Will B and C gone too?

```
-(void) foo
{
A * a= [[A alloc]init];
A.b = [[B alloc]init];
A.b.c = [[C alloc]init];
//end of function what happen here? Will a, A.b and A.b.c gone too? How exactly that work?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your classes need to release their references when they are de-allocated.

I don't think that ARC changes anything here (except inserting the release calls automatically).

Comment: That is very unclear. What do you mean by my classes need to release their references? We don't even have dealloc method in ARC.

Comment: Yes, you don't have to do that. ARC will generate this code for you automatically. But the mechanism is the same as pre-ARC: There is code that gets run by the object "on its dying breath" that releases all its references (and if that somehow does not happen, there is a leak).

Comment: so dealloc method is still there except that it's not done by us anymore.

Answer (score 3):

A is in the heap (the pointer is in the stack).
And... yes.. If there are no more strong reference to an object it is released immediately.

ARC is not a garbage collector. It is simply a compile time feature. It automatically adds retain, release and autorelease statements to objects.
So.. In ARC mode your dealloc method automatically calls release on B. And the dealloc method of B calls release on C.

BTW: you can implement a dealloc method. You can't call release in it.. so you can close socket or free resources....

Comment: +1 for "ARC is not a garbage collector". The collection mechanism is the same as before, using reference counting that needs be correctly implemented in "user-space". ARC just helps with that implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Using ARC and marking those references as strong ensures that the compiler synthesize release calls to those objects in the dealloc method.

So, yes, assuming there are no other references to objects B and C, they are released as a part of A's dying breath :)